# Otimização de lógica

Tags: php, if, lógica

Tenho a seguinte logica que preciso otimizar, utilizando PHP

```
Parâmetros:
máximo
mínimo
alerta

Se ultrapassar o nível máximo enviar um alerta
    Se alerta já tiver sido enviado não enviar nada
Se o nível voltar ao normal enviar alerta
```

O mesmo comportamento com o mínimo:

```
Se ultrapassar o nível mínimo enviar um alerta
    Se alerta já tiver sido enviado não enviar nada
Se o nível voltar ao normal enviar alerta
```

O problema é que dessa forma a cadeia de if e else fica muita extensa.
Alguém teria uma ideia pra otimizar e deixar o mais simples possível

Comment: Você já tentou utilizar o operador ternário?

Comment: Isso sequer é um algoritmo compreensível. Isso pode ser um requisito sem detalhes.

Answer (score 4):

É possível otimizar da seguinte forma, detectar se o valor está 'fora' da faixa (maior que o maximo ou menor que o mínimo) e se o alerta já foi enviado, nesse caso não faz nada, pois:

- ou o alerta já foi enviado.
- ou o valor está na faixa do 'normal' entre o maximo e o mínimo.
- ou o valor está abaixo do mínimo ou acima do maximo porém o alerta não foi enviado.

Veja o código abaixo:

```
$max = 30;
$min = 5;
$alerta = false;
$valor = 6;

if( ($valor < $min || $valor > $max) && !$alerta) {
    echo 'enviar alerta';
    $alerta = true;
}else{
    echo 'alerta já enviado ou valor normal';
}
```

Exemplo:

```
        6       5        6      30        false
if( ($valor < $min || $valor > $max) && !$alerta)
          false            false          true
```

Veja o parentese agrupando as comparações de faixa o resultado dela é conectada por um por `E` lógico a segunda parte apenas nega o valor de `$alerta` nesse caso pode ser traduzido como `if(false && true)` logo o resultado é falso.

Answer (score 1):

```
$nivel = ; // Nível 
$alerta = false; // Não foi enviado nenhum alerta
$msg = "";

if ($nivel == 5) { // Nível máximo é 5
  $msg = (!$alerta) ? "alerta - nível em seu estado máximo": "";
}
if ($nivel <= 3) { // Nível normal é abaixo ou igual a 3
 $msg = "alerta - nível em seu estado normal";
}

if ($msg != "") {
    echo $msg;
    $alerta = true;
}
```